# Is there a way to play Unikong on a phone?

Tags: discussion, unikong

I'm bored on my commute. Can I play it through the mobile app somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly no. This is the one thing we didn't think of - touch input. :(

Comment: Hmm. But it does run at least. Wonder if I can force the iPhone keyboard to open while it is running.

Comment: How can you not of thought of touch input in 2016?

Comment: It runs on my iPad. It's getting rid of it that's the problem.

Comment: @Turnip https://twitter.com/aalear/status/713153888619257856

Comment: @AdamLear  Good one. I need that for my cube